# Updating front end data as backend does analysis

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I've been self studying web design and want to implement something, but I'm really not sure how to accomplish it, even if I can.

The only frontend I have dealt with is angular 4, and the only backend I have dealt with is django rest framework. I have managed to get user models done in drf, and the frontend to get the user authenticated with json web tokens, and done different kinds of get and post requests.

What I want to do is on the front end have a button, when the button is hit, it will send some get request, that basically runs a text mining algorithm that will produce a list, it may take some time to fully complete, maybe in the range of 20-30 seconds, but I don't want the user to wait that long to get back the single response containing the fully compiled list.

Is it possible to say create a table in angular, and then every couple of seconds the backend sends another response containing more data, where the backend then appends the new results to that table. Something like:

1. 00.00s | button -> GET request
2. 01.00s drf starts analysis
3. 05.00s drf returns the first estimated 10% of overall list
4. 09.00s drf finds 10% more, returns estimated 20% of overall list

then repeat this process until the algorithm has stopped. The list will be very small in size, probably a list of around 20 strings, of about 15 words in each,..

I already tried in django to send multiple responses in a for loop, but the angular front end just receives the first one and then doesnt listen anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. For each request will be one response, not multiple.

You have two options:
- Just start your algorithm with an endpoint like `/start`, and check the state in an interval on an endpoint like `/state`
- Read about websockets or try [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) (or [angularfire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)). This provides a two way communication

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will look into what you proposed.